# How do Ordered Target Statistics work for CatBoost?

Tags: order-statistics, catboost, target-encoders

This question follows closely [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09516) .

I'm trying to fully understand how Ordered Target Statistics (TS) (for CatBoost) works. E.g. the CatBoost algorithm uses this method to group categorical features through estimatation of numerical values $\hat{x}_{k}^{i} \approx \mathbb{E}\left(y \mid x^{i}=x_{k}^{i}\right)$  instead of one-hot-encode them.

Since this estimate can be noisy for low-frequency categories, one can smooth it by some prior p so that :

$\hat{x}_{k}^{i}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{\left\{x_{j}^{i}=x_{k}^{i}\right\}} \cdot y_{j}+a p}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{\left\{x_{j}^{i}=x_{k}^{i}\right\}}+a}$ where $a>0$ is some parameter.

Now, one uses the ordering principle which translates to me to order the (whole) data set $\mathcal{D}$ or some subsets of the dataset $\mathcal{D}_k$ given some ordering function. I anticipate that the ordering function in the CatBoost algorithm is the artificial "time" which they define as a random permutation $\sigma$ of the training examples. Then, for each example they use all the available "history".

What is meant by "history" in this method?

My best guess would be the following. In each step a random permutation is applied to $\mathcal{D}$. Afterwards $\mathcal{D}$ is split into training and test examples. Then the test examples were expanded with all the training examples of the past steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catboost in order to calculate the ordered target statistics defines various permutations of the training data. Now at each step of the gradient boosting it chooses one of the permutation at random in order to calculate ordered ts.

Now the ***history refers the sample that appears before***. Now lets look at the random sample from permutation below:

[image]

for Row ID - 9 , history comprises of Row ID - 2 but not Row ID - 3 as in this permutation it occurs after Row ID - 9

Answer (score 0):

"*What is meant by "history" in this method?*"

The history of a data point $i$ refers to all data points appearing before data point $i$ in a given permutation.

"*Afterwards D is split into training and test examples. Then the test examples were expanded with all the training examples of the past steps.*"

The artificial time only applies to training dataset $\mathcal{D}$. In the testing phase, the whole training dataset $\mathcal{D}$ is used to do TS encoding.

To avoid target leakage, we can actually divide the training set $\mathcal{D}$ into $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$, and then using $\mathcal{D}_1$ to do TS encoding and $\mathcal{D}_2$ for training. But this is a waste of your training data. They then figured out a way, i.e. ordered TS encoding, to avoid target leakage and at the same time utilize full training dataset $\mathcal{D}$. This idea is not only used to encode categorical features but also to build base learners in boosting. This target leakage in the boosting machine has been overlooked by people until catboost.

The ordered TS encoding is explained in other answer. It is worth noting that the encoding has large variance for data points with short history, and that is why they utilized many permutations (or artificial times) in different iterations of the boosting process. Notice that this does not mean that different artificial times are used to encode different categorical features. It is actually the same sampled artificial time used to do all ordered TS encoding for all categorical features and also for constructing the base learner.